# jQuery - acquiring variables from dynamic form for multiple functions

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have started using jQuery few days ago, and although I found information on how to solve any problems that I have encountered (or at least get it working by some workarounds), I seem to be stuck on the current issue:

I have a form that has a variable number of fields - the number of fields may change depending on user input at any point, and I achieved that using AJAX; Since I want to preserve the information user entered every time form is regenerated, I post data from the form fields and use it to repopulate newly generated fields every time the number of fields is changed; This all works (although I know I am doing it not the *right* way, more on it further).

What I need to do is use the values from form fields for another AJAX call to generate another table on the page; I use the following code to acquire the field values for the first AJAX call, it is generated by php and spans from jq_calc11 to jq_calc99 (depending on number of fields). I understand that this is probably not the *correct* way, yet I could not figure out how to post a two-dimensional array using jQuery.

```
$('#ts_addfields').change(function()
{   
 var comp_select=$('#ts_addfields').val();
var jq_calc11=$('#tb_calc11').val(); 
 var jq_calc21=$('#tb_calc21').val(); 
 var jq_calc31=$('#tb_calc31').val(); 
 var jq_calc41=$('#tb_calc41').val(); 
 var jq_calc51=$('#tb_calc51').val(); 
 var jq_calc61=$('#tb_calc61').val(); 
 var jq_calc71=$('#tb_calc71').val(); 
 var jq_calc81=$('#tb_calc81').val(); 
 $('#calculator_input').load('/elements/AJAX-addfields.php',{addFields: comp_select, pCalc11:jq_calc11, pCalc21:jq_calc21, pCalc31:jq_calc31, pCalc41:jq_calc41, pCalc51:jq_calc51, pCalc61:jq_calc61, pCalc71:jq_calc71, pCalc81:jq_calc81});    
   });
```

My question now is, how can I re-use the values of these variables for a different AJAX call? I don't think having another potential 99 lines to be generated via php for another function is a good idea, so I looked into possibility of placing these values in a seperate function, and call it from inside the `$('#ts_addfields').change(function()` or another function. 
I've tried various variations of the following, yet I cannot find a way how to run the function that would read the variables;

```
jQuery.fn.calcVars = function(){
 var jq_calc11=$('#tb_calc11').val(); 
 var jq_calc21=$('#tb_calc21').val(); 
 var jq_calc31=$('#tb_calc31').val(); 
 var jq_calc41=$('#tb_calc41').val(); 
 var jq_calc51=$('#tb_calc51').val(); 
 var jq_calc61=$('#tb_calc61').val(); 
 var jq_calc71=$('#tb_calc71').val(); 
 var jq_calc81=$('#tb_calc81').val(); 
 };

$('#ts_addfields').change(function()
{   
 var comp_select=$('#ts_addfields').val();
 $(this).calcVars();
$('#calculator_input').load('/elements/AJAX-addfields.php',{addFields: comp_select, pCalc11:jq_calc11, pCalc21:jq_calc21, pCalc31:jq_calc31, pCalc41:jq_calc41, pCalc51:jq_calc51, pCalc61:jq_calc61, pCalc71:jq_calc71, pCalc81:jq_calc81});    
   });
```

Any code I've tried returns "jq_calc*xx*" not defined error on firebug.

Could someone point me to the right direction?

Comment: as far as posting a two dimensional array, you can use json: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6783772/serialize-json-2-dimensional-array-send-two-arrays-or-other

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could try this:

```
var str = $("form").serialize();
```

http://api.jquery.com/serialize/