# How to convert JS array to JSON, before passing that to controller (using AJAX - POST call)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, jquery

I ve a JS array, comprising multiple JS objects.
I want to convert JS array to JSON type, & pass that to controller (using AJAX - POST call).
So that I can retrieve the values from the Array of Objects, in my controller & save them in DB.

NB: I ve tried using `$.stringify(myArry)`, but its not able to send data to controller in JSON format. Also I cant use `$.toJSON(myArray)`, as I m not allowed to include a new plugin in our solution. :(

Plz suggest me any other idea.

Else if anyone can let me know how to deserelize the array in cotroller, that I ve sent by using $.stringify(myArry), that would also great.
Something like

```
var result = JavaScriptConvert.DeserializeObject(inputContent, JsonDataType);
```

Answer (score 1):

Per this post, it looks like you'll have to add another plug-in:

[JSON stringify missing from jQuery 1.4.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2277405/json-stringify-missing-from-jquery-1-4-1)

The Google solution looks good: http://code.google.com/p/jquery-json/

Or just use the JSON object from Crockford: https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js